# Which row has the most 1s in a 0-1 matrix with all 1s "on the left"?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

**Problem**

Each row of an n x n matrix consists of 1's and 0's such that in any row, all 1's come before any 0's. Find row containing most no of 1's in O(n).

**Example**

```
1 1 1 1 1 0  <- Contains maximum number of 1s, return index 1
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I found this question in my algorithms book. The best I could do took O(n logn) time. 
How to do this in O(n)?

Comment: What is n here? Number of rows? Number of coloumns? Number of cells?

Comment: The question states `n x n`, so n is both columns and rows.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Start at 1,1.

If the cell contains 1, you're on the longest row so far; write it down and go right.
If the cell contains 0, go down.
If the cell is out of bounds, you're done.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it in `O(N)` as follows:

Start at `A[i][j]` with `i=j=0`.

```
          1, keep moving to the right by doing j++
A[i][j] = 
          0, move down to the next row by doing i++
```

When you reach the last row or the last column, the value of `j` will be the answer.

Pseudo code:

```
Let R be number of rows
Let C be number of columns

Let i = 0
Let j = 0   
Let max1Row = 0

while ( i<R && j<C )
   if ( matrix[i][j] == 1 )
      j++
      max1Row = i
   else
      i++
end-while


print "Max 1's = j"
print "Row number with max 1's = max1Row"
```

Comment: This is wrong...what if your first cell [0, 0] contains a 0 and the rest cells in that row contains all 1. And all the rest of the cell in the subsequent rows contain only 0. Then you answer would be i where i is the maximum row number and j would be 0.

Comment: @Swaranga Sarma: You need to read the question carefully **all 1's come before any 0's**

Comment: The code seems incorrect specially `"if ( matrix[i][j] == 1 )     j++
      max1Row = i"` part. You are not keeping track of the row-number with the maximum number of 1

Comment: It would be good if we start from right to left rather than travelling from left to right so that we can skip most of rows if it ends with 0

Answer (score 2):

Start with the first row. Keep the row `R` that has the most numbers of 1s and the index i of the last 1 of `R`. in each iteration compare the current row with the row `R` on the index `i`. if the current row has a `0` on position `i`, the row `R` is still the answer. 
Otherwise, return the index of the current row. Now we just have to find the last 1 of the current row. Iterate from index `i` up to the last 1 of the current row, set `R` to this row and `i` to this new index.

```
              i
              |  
              v 
R->   1 1 1 1 1 0  
|
v     1 1 1 0 0 0 (Compare ith index of this row)
      1 0 0 0 0 0         Repeat
      1 1 1 1 0 0           "
      1 1 1 1 0 0           "
      1 1 0 0 0 0           "
```

Answer (score 0):

Some C code to do this.

```
int n = 6;
int maxones = 0, maxrow = -1, row = 0, col = 0;
while(row < n) {
    while(col < n && matrix[row][col] == 1) col++;
    if(col == n) return row;
    if(col > maxones){
        maxrow = row;
        maxones = col;
    }
    row++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] getMax1withRow(int [][] matrix){
    int [] result=new int[2];
    int rows=matrix.length;
    int cols=matrix[0].length;
    int i=0, j=0;
    int max_row=0;// This will show row with maximum 1. Intialing pointing to 0th row.
    int max_one=0;// max one
    while(i< rows){
        while(matrix[i][j]==1){
            j++;
        }
        if(j==n){
             result[0]=n;
             result[1]=i;
             return result;
        }
        if(j>max_one){
             max_one=j;
             max_row=i;
        }
        j=0;// Again start from the first column
        i++;// increase row number
    }
    result[0]=max_one;
    result[1]=max_row;
    return result;
}
```

Time complexity => O(row+col), In worse case If every row has n-1 one except last row which have n 1s then we have be travel till last row.

Comment: Your time complexity is `O(n^2)` because `j=0;// Again start from the first column`. The whole point of Thom's answer is that you don't have to go back to the beginning of the row because you know that if the next row doesn't have a `1` in the current column, it can't be the row with the most `1`'s.