# Find out the row which has the maximum number of 1s in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix with only 1s and 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388571/matrix-with-only-1s-and-0s)

Given an NxN array which is made up of only 1s and 0s such that for each row, all the 1s come before the 0s.C

Answer (score 3):

I saw a similar question here some time ago here on SO, <strike>if someone finds the link, please edit.</strike> EDIT: Found the link: [Matrix with only 1s and 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388571/matrix-with-only-1s-and-0s). The solution was:

```
1. Start in the first row, most-left column
2. Go right until you hit a 0, if so, go down
3. If you hit a 1, the current row will be your new "best row"
4. Repeat from 2 until you either hit the bottom or the right border
```

Given an NxN array, this checks N cells in the best, N*2-1 cells in the worst case, so it's O(N) in terms of rows/columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your homework solution is:

Start in the first cell of the first row. If it contains a 1, move to the next cell in the same row. If it contains a 0, move to the same cell in the next row. Repeat this until you have processed all rows.

The row where you have moved within the row for the last time is the row with the maximum number of ones.